# Alert a variable in function

Tags: javascript

I create a function that contain parameter , and i alert the response in another function , that's why i create a global variable "imageServer" and i want to alert the imageServer in the "AlertFunction" function.

```
var imageServer ;

function win(r) 
{
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);       
    imageServer = r.response;

}

function AlertFunction()
    {
    alert(imageServer);
    }
```

i want to alert the r.response in the "AlertFunction" function, but nothing is displaying

Comment: When are `win(r)` and `AlertFunction()` fired?

Comment: is `r` an XHR object?

Comment: So, the console.log statement gives you the expected output? And what do you mean with "nothing is displaying"? Does it mean the alert is empty or it doesn't even pop up?

Comment: alert Doesn't  pop up

Comment: Is it possible your browser is simply blocking the pop-up? Also can you add a `console.log('Debug');` to your `AlertFunction()` to make sure it does get there?

Comment: @Katsudoka in that case, you should show us the code in which you call the function `AlertFunction`. With what you have given us so far, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the alert function from the win function.

```
function win(r) 
{
console.log("Response = " + r.response);       
imageServer = r.response;
AlertFunction()
}
```